# Estimate Size of Data in Google BigTable

Tags: database, nosql, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to use Google BigTable and wanted to know how to calculate the estimated size that will be required by the Data I store.

I will store data in the following schema:

```
code string
name string
is_active boolean
score float
active_time timestamp
```

It's estimated that the Store will carry ~1 million such rows.
Is there any way to estimate this?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Big Table is a No SQL database, so it stores [keys and values](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#what-its-good-for) in arbitrary byte arrays. Each value has maximum as 10MB, Unfortunately there isn't a very precise rule but you should expect the same order of magnitude as the logical data size.

Here is an example of [BigQuery](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-estimate-google-bigquery-pricing/#storage-data) and  it's quiet similar for Big Table excepting the price per month. [You can check the Cloud Big Table Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing#storage) for the Big Table Storage Pricing for GB per Month.

You can have an estimation of your data size multiplying the bytes required for each row by ~1 Million. Each row size can vary and can be calculated by having a sum of each attribute bytes in the row.

Here is also [Google Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to estimate pricing for each of the Google Products depending on the Storage (However this is not your case).